# Count number of records based on date from csv file in shell script

Tags: unix

i have one CSV file in which data is like in column, Column A is name and Column b is date

```
Abc 9-DEC-19
BED 10-AUG-19
XYZ 20-AUG-19
AAA 20-JUL-19
```

I want to count the number of records from CSV file based on the date
Suppose July last month there is 4 entry in CSV file
so I want that 4 records from my script.

Comment: `grep JUL file`?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  CSV stands for "Comma-separated values".  No commas in there.  You should take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Actually, `grep -c JUL file` will return the number of lines that match the "JUL" characters.

Comment: its not like only for july, i have to run the script every month of 1st so i want that script get the total no. of records of last month